# GWT doesn't properly display in Internet Explorer when passing through DNS

Tags: gwt

I have the problem that the application take all browser space events if I set the size of the RootLayoutPanel. This problem appears only when a go through DNS, not when I connect directly to the machine:

For example, http://10.10.3.1:8080/MyApp/ works fine. The main screen is according to the size(1024x768).

http://nameOfMachine:8080/MyApp/ (nameOfMachine is set to 10.20.3.136). The widget appears, but they are in the wrong place. The bottom element move according to the browser size.

Answer (score 1):

If in IE8 or IE9, check the browser mode and document mode from the Internet Explorer Developer Tools.

In most cases, you'd want to force IE=8 (or IE=9, or IE=Edge) mode by adding a `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8">` to your page.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288325(v=vs.85).aspx for more on "document compatibility".